# How does one pronounce this particle's name?

Tags: particle-physics, soft-question, terminology

How would you read the following particles' names in a conversation in English?  I am looking for some "proper" way of doing it.  Say, imagine you are reading a technical description in a semi-formal occasion that you would like to avoid being lousy or overly simplistic.

$$\Delta(1750)^0 P_{31}$$
$$\bar\Delta(1910)^0 P_{31}$$
$$\Delta(1910)^- P_{31}$$

[EDIT]
One additional question, would you write $\Delta^0(1750) P_{31}$ or $\Delta(1750)^0 P_{31}$ ?

Comment: I'm not saying this is on topic, but I edited the output of the Wolfram Alpha links inline.

Comment: I voted to close since it is not really an informative question as far as physics goes. As for reading  say: "Delta zero  seventeen fifty , pee thirty one", "antidelta zero nineteen ten","Delta minus nineteen ten"

Comment: @annav I would say if it is worth the effort to provide the answer at all, it's worth posting it as an actual answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For questions about resonances and particles the [Particle Data Group](http://pdg.lbl.gov/) is the best reference.

One can find the whole [Delta resonance](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/tables/rpp2011-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf) family  and remind oneself what each number is standing for, and thus know how to pronounce the symbol.

The number in parenthesis is the mass in MeV. The superscript is the charge of the particular resonance displayed on the plot, presumably. S,P,D,... are by convention the labels of the angular momentum [quantum number](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/tables/rpp2011-tab-baryons-Delta.pdf) "L" , and the two numbers are the numerators of the isospin and J quantum number ( J is the  total angular momentum quantum number).

So the first one is  read as : Delta zero  seventeen fifty (Pee three one) or (Pee three halves one half). etc. (The superscript of parity is missing in your information.) The bar over a symbol denotes an antiparticle, antiDelta(1910)zero in the second line.

I would try and put the charge next to the main symbol, your first option but the other way is clear also.

For similar questions the [naming scheme for hadrons](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/rpp2011-rev-naming-scheme-hadrons.pdf) would be a help in comprehension as well as pronunciation.

Comment: One additional question, would you write $\Delta^0(1750) P_{31}$ or $\Delta(1750)^0 P_{31}$ ?

Comment: I would try and put the charge next to the main symbol, your first option.